# How do I place multiple columns from a single row into a single textbox or label?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can find a lot of info about `parsing` but I would like to put them together.  I am trying to get the `City, State, and Zip` and place them in a single `Label` on a winform like 'City, State  Zip'  here is what I have gotten to but they will not get together.

```
   while (sqlDataReader.Read())
   {
       label_vendor_Address.Text = sqlDataReader["Vendor_Address"].ToString();

       string vendor_City = sqlDataReader["Vendor_City"].ToString();
       string vendor_State_Prov = sqlDataReader["Vendor_State_Prov"].ToString();
       string vendor_Zip_Country_Code = sqlDataReader["Vendor_Zip_Country_Code"].ToString();

       label_vendor_City_State_Zip.Text = vendor_City, vendor_State_Prov, vendor_Zip_Country_Code;
   }
```

I am sure that I am missing something very simple.  Help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Looks fine. What do you mean "they will not get together". Please be _specific_ about what happens, and how that's different from what you want to happen. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do note Enigmativity's comment...the code you posted shouldn't compile at all. I'm assuming that you don't have that literally, since you wouldn't be able to run it if that's what you had.

Comment: @PeterDuniho; I am not sure who you think you are along with the  other 5 that think my question is off topic.  In the end I learned the answer to my question.  I have been trying to find the answer to another question `Why doesn't my Form1_Load() event fire` and all I can find is work a-rounds which I did on my own.  I would like to know the answer to `why did it work and now it doesn't` what makes the Form1_Load event stop working?

Comment: Here's a little hint for you Dave: when five people in a community all agree your question doesn't meet the criteria for being "on-topic", then you will be better served looking more closely at _why_ that happened, than you will be by acting out your indignation in public against them. You can start by looking at your question objectively and thinking about whether _anything_ in the question actually led to someone else giving you the answer you needed (nothing did), and whether anyone else will find that same answer to help them in the future (they won't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it as simple as this:

```
label_vendor_City_State_Zip.Text = vendor_City + ", " + vendor_State_Prov + "  " + vendor_Zip_Country_Code;
```

Surely, not though, as your code would not compile. Can you provide code that can compile?

Comment: You were correct, the double quote is required.  Once I added the `Vendor_Zip_Country_Code` to my sqlCommand it did compile and work. I did learn that " " are required if there are more than 2 spaces or a 'comma and a space' as the single quotes don't work.  Thanks for taking a look a t my question.